# How to set an onTouchListener for multiple ImageButtons

Tags: android, listener, imagebutton

I have this:

```
// Set up touch listeners for all the buttons
    View cardButton = findViewById(R.id.C_0);
    cardButton.setTag(0);
    cardButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
    View cardButton1 = findViewById(R.id.C_1);
    cardButton1.setTag(1);
    cardButton1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    View cardButton2 = findViewById(R.id.C_2);
    cardButton2.setTag(2);
    cardButton2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    View cardButton3 = findViewById(R.id.C_3);
    cardButton3.setTag(3);
    cardButton3.setOnTouchListener(this);
    View cardButton4 = findViewById(R.id.C_4);
    cardButton4.setTag(4);
    cardButton4.setOnTouchListener(this);
    View cardButton5 = findViewById(R.id.C_5);
    cardButton5.setTag(5);
    cardButton5.setOnTouchListener(this);
    View cardButton6 = findViewById(R.id.C_6);
    cardButton6.setTag(6);
    cardButton6.setOnTouchListener(this);
    View cardButton7 = findViewById(R.id.C_7);
    cardButton7.setTag(7);
    cardButton7.setOnTouchListener(this);
    View cardButton8 = findViewById(R.id.C_8);
    cardButton8.setTag(8);
    cardButton8.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

But I need to generate it programmatically so I can't have it written out like this.  Unfortunately, I have tried three methods but none work.  Firstly:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        String bufferName = "C_" + i;
        int tempid = getResources().getIdentifier(bufferName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        View cardButton = findViewById(tempid);
        cardButton.setTag(i);
        cardButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
```

This gives me a NullPointerException.  I'm not sure how to pinpoint it.  Also, the android thing says you shouldn't use getIdentifier anyway because it is expensive.

Next attempt:

```
ViewGroup rootLayout=(ViewGroup) sv.getRootView();
    View v;
    int id = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rootLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        v = rootLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof View)
        {
            v.setTag(id);
            id += 1;
            v.setOnTouchListener(this);
        };
    }
```

No errors here, but none of the buttons work anymore.  Either the listeners are not getting set or the touches aren't getting recorded properly or whatever.

Third attempt:

```
int[] ids = {R.id.C_0, R.id.C_1, R.id.C_2, R.id.C_3, R.id.C_4, R.id.C_5, R.id.C_6, R.id.C_7, R.id.C_8};
    for (int id:ids)
    {
        ImageView b = (ImageView)findViewById(id);
        b.setTag(ids);
        b.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
```

This is the worst method and I don't want to use it, but even this would not work.  I was getting ClassCastException.  I tried using `ImageButton b = (ImageButton)findViewById(id);` but that still got me the same error.  Sorry if this is totally newb, but I've spent hours trying to figure out a way to do this.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly:**
Your first attempt is very close... 
You are using the wrong type here:

```
int tempid = getResources().getIdentifier(bufferName, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

You want an `id`, use:

```
int tempid = getResources().getIdentifier(bufferName, "id", getPackageName());
```

---

**Next attempt:**
This one looks okay, maybe it is the OnTouchListener that has an error.

---

**Third attempt:**
The ClassCastException simply means that whatever View type you declared in the XML must be the class the View type you use in your Java code...

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.  Replacing "drawable" with "id" was exactly what needed to be done.  Not sure what is wrong with the second attempt, maybe because the root layout I was trying to pull from was a ScrollView?  Not sure though I had tried other implementations with that one, even one using getRootView().  The OnTouchListener worked fine with my original code at the top there, and now it works with the first one since I fixed it.

Comment: Glad I could help. I think the second approach returns a different layout than you expected. It is the grandparent or great-grandparent of the Views you want.